# Angular AOT lazy-loaded modules with Ionic-app-scripts (webpack)

Tags: angular, lazy-loading, ionic3, angular2-aot, angular-router

We're trying to create an angular (4) and ionic (3) app from the same codebase using ionic-app-scripts to build. We have an issue where the production build is not working for angular ( using angular-router with lazy loaded components ).

Has anyone successfully integrated an AOT webpack loader with the ionic-app-scripts? We're attempting to use ng-router-loader and add it to the chain of loaders but we either get a runtime compiler not present error or webpack build error if the loader is too far down the loader chain for ng-router-loader at index.js 29:14

```
Module build failed: TypeError: this.call is not a function
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, there is no default provided for loading lazy feature modules from with angular routing. Only for pages in ionic.

We are also using angular (5) routes in an ionic 3 application with nested feature modules which should be lazy loaded. But this does not work with the default ionic-app-scripts configuration and we decided it is too time consuming to dig into it.

Since ionic 4 they will be using just the ionic-cli without all the ionic-app-scripts configuration. Because of that I would suggest waiting for ionic 4 and upgrading later on and stick for now with a complete bundle (without lazy loading but with minifying and AOT) like we did.

For this to work with our separation of our feature modules, we had to export the routes from the feature modules and merge them, like this:

```js
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forChild([
            {
                path: DashboardRoutingRouteNames.Dashboard,
                component: DashboardComponent,
                children: [
                    {
                        path: '',
                        redirectTo: DashboardRoutingRouteNames.Overview,
                        pathMatch: 'full'
                    },
                    /**
                     * This is a workaround because AOT is not working correct with ionic 3 (default ionic-app-scripts configuration) and lazy loaded feature modules of angular.
                     */
                    dashboardOverviewRoutes,
                    dashboardAccountRoutes
                ]
            }
        ])
    ],
    exports: [
        RouterModule
    ]
})
export class DashboardRoutingModule {
}
```

```js
export const dashboardAccountRoutes: Route = {
    path: DashboardRoutingRouteNames.Account,
    children: [
        {
            path: '',
            component: AccountComponent
        }
    ]
};
```